# Выполнить последние сетевые запросы при появлении интернета

Tags: android

При отсутствии интернета при выполнении сетевого запроса выводится пустой фрагмент с иконкой "Обновить". При нажатии должны выполниться те запросы, которые не выполнились из-за отсутствии интернета (их может быть несколько независимых друг от друга). Как можно это реализовать? Может, есть библиотека или паттерн? Спасибо за ответ.

Answer (score 0):

Так в чем проблема? Используйте ретрофит (https://github.com/square/retrofit) для запросов. Если запрос завершился удачно - показываете данные, если не удачно, то в соответствующем обработчике вызываете пустой фрагмент с кнопокой обновить. На кнопку вешаете такой же запрос.